# Python GUI Tkinter console error: "invalid command name"

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I am encountering this error:

```
invalid command name "1659368897984update"
while executing
"1659368897984update"
("after" script)
invalid command name "1659360881536check_dpi_scaling"
while executing
"1659360881536check_dpi_scaling"
("after" script)
```

On this code:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import time



class Setting():

   def Page_Confrugation(self):
      window_width = 600
      window_height = 400

      # Get screen dimensions
      screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
      screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

      # Calculate the window's position for precise centering
      x = (screen_width - window_width) // 2
      y = (screen_height - window_height) // 2

      self.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")



class SplashScreen(ctk.CTk, Setting):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
        
      self.overrideredirect(True) # framless window
      self.Page_Confrugation()


      # Display the image on the splash screen
      #   self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image)
      #   self.image_label = tk.Label(self, image=self.image)
      #   self.image_label.pack()

      # Display the loading bar on the splash screen
      self.loading_bar = ctk.CTkProgressBar(self, orientation="horizontal", mode="determinate",
                width=800,
                height=20,
                corner_radius=0
            )
      self.loading_bar.place(x=0,y=350)
      self.loading_bar.set(0)

      self.update_loading_bar()

   def update_loading_bar(self):
      num_steps = 11
      for i in range(num_steps):
         value = i / (num_steps - 1)
         if self.loading_bar.get() < 0.9:
            self.loading_bar.set(value)
            self.update()
            time.sleep(0.2)
         else:
            self.destroy()
            MainWindow().mainloop()

class MainWindow(ctk.CTk, Setting):

   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

      self.Page_Confrugation()
      ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark") 



      self.label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text='Welcome',
      font=('calbari', 40,'bold'),
      text_color='#fff',
      )

      self.label.pack(pady=(100,0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   
   app = SplashScreen()
   app.mainloop()
```

Comment: what does `self.overrideredirect` do, or where is it defined ?

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @D.L "To create a Frameless window, we will use the overrideredirect() method." https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-frameless-window/

Comment: You are trying to create a new window from the destroyed main window, and you get an error. https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/close-tkinter-window-in-python#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20root,widgets%20and%20exits%20the%20mainloop. A more correct method is to use toplevel windows. https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkToplevel.